# Drop duplicate Pandas and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a script for a call centre that wishes to be able to upload millions of records from a csv file to a database, filtering out all duplicate phone numbers from the upload. To do this I am using Pandas and SQLAlchemy

```
df = read_csv('test.csv')

rd = models.session.query(Test).all()
```

I know there is the `drop_duplicates()` in pandas but can only find examples of removing duplicates from the same dataframe. Is this even applicable in my case

UPDATE:

This is what I have so far thanks to the help of others.

```
df = read_csv('phones.csv')

result_dict = [u.__dict__ for u in models.session.query(Dedupe).all()]

df['tel'] = df.index

rd = DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict)

print df[~df['tel'].isin(rd['tel'].unique())]
```

It is still printing out all of the csv. Even if there are duplicates

Comment: Sorry what is the problem here? you can do `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='phone_number')` shouldn't that just work?

Comment: wouldn't that only look for duplications in df and not duplications between df and rd

Comment: Yes it would, in which case you could filter your read df so `df[~df['phone_number'].isin(rd['phone_number'].unique())]]` I don't know if you need to call `.unique` on `df['phone_number']` or not

Comment: It depends on your use case here and the frequency of updates, it may be more performant to cache all the phone numbers and then check against this when uploading so the data doesn't go near the DB unless it's genuine new data

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do :) I am trying out what you suggested

Comment: I meant caching of the existing phone numbers in the DB

Comment: Yeah, I agree with caching. It would be very inefficient to query millions of phone number records every time you update the database.

Comment: I have updated my question with what i have so far. It is still printing out all the csv, even if there are duplicates.

Comment: Is the index of the read_csv file the phone numbers? A small sample of the file would help.

Comment: Also, verify output of SQL query to make sure data type in the `rd['tel']` and `df['tel']` columns is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this illustrates how to check against the phone numbers in the database.

```
In [59]:  data = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['number'])

In [60]: data
Out[60]: 
   number
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
8       8
9       9

In [61]: check = range(5)

In [62]: check
Out[62]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [63]: data = data[~data['number'].isin(check)]

In [64]: data
Out[64]: 
   number
5       5
6       6
7       7
8       8
9       9
```

Replace **data** with your upload table and **check** will need to be a queried list of phone numbers from your database.